# Create dynamic form programmatically after completion of http request

Tags: swift, form-submit

I created swift form using this library https://github.com/ortuman/SwiftForms . I want the form load once the http request have completed or any other solutions I can get the http results to load on the form. Here is my code

[image: form]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to append the new section to the form and reload table at the end of func loadLayerForm() as following:

```
//add new section to the form
self.form.sections.append(newSection)

//reload table view 
tableView.reloadData()
```